# Show qemu command line from virsh

Tags: linux-kvm, qemu, libvirt, virsh

I am debugging a problem with a libvirt VM starting, and I want to see the exact command line that it is going to use to start `qemu`.  Is this possible using `virsh` or some other utility?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can consult the libvirt logs in:

```
/var/log/libvirt/qemu/$vmname.log
```

Source: https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Windows_Virtio_Drivers

Answer (score 2):

Just saw this question. In the hope it helps others, the easiest way to see the qemu command that was used, while the VM is running, is:

```
ps -ef | grep qemu-system-x86
```

Comment: Thanks but this doesn't help. Like I said in the question, I was trying to debug a VM that wouldn't start. The qemu process exited immediately, so looking at the running process list doesn't show what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

It is also possible using [`virsh`](https://libvirt.org/manpages/virsh.html) with the `domxml-to-native` subcommand:

```sh
virsh domxml-to-native qemu-argv --domain mydomain
```